# An Issue animating a new TextView added to the activity on Nexus4 vs Other devices

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-animation

Im very new to java and android programming.

I am trying to create a button that when pressed, a text will appear at the location of the click and immediately fade out.
At the moment, the problem is that when clicked - the text does appear, but the animation doesn't play, and the text disappears after a few seconds (just like I want).

I have edited this question a few times down bellow, following some progress on solving this problem with great help from the guys replying. Thanks!

The code I tried is this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mClickMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);

    mClickMe.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                int xClickPos = (int) event.getRawX();
                int yClickPos = (int) event.getRawY();

                final TextView scorePop = new TextView(getApplicationContext());                    

                scorePop.setText("+10");
                scorePop.setX(xClickPos);
                scorePop.setY(yClickPos);
                scorePop.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);

                // Create the score pop animation                   
                Animation scoreAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
                scoreAnimation.setDuration(1000);

                scoreAnimation.setAnimationListener (new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        scorePop.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        mRelativeLayout.removeView(scorePop);

                    }
                });                 
                mRelativeLayout.addView(scorePop);
                scorePop.setAnimation(scoreAnimation);

                scoreAnimation.start();


            }
            return false;
        }
    });



}
```

EDIT: I have also noticed that if the button is clicked quickly on different spots, the text appears at those spots and disappears with a "choppy" fade. Yet still, if clicked once - the text appears and disappears but no animation.
Thanks for the help!

EDIT 2: With the help I got here it seems the problem has something to do with the device. I am using Nexus 4, and running an emulator to test my apps as Nexus 4 as well. Oddly, running emulator for another device such as Galaxy Nexus seemed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
I was able to recreate your original bug and it had something to do with `setX(),setY()`. After executing either of those methods the `TextView` gets "numb" and won't animate. The workarround I figured was to set the layout's **margins** not the `TextView`'s coordinates:

```
        // Set the margins instead of the actual position
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params=(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)scorePop.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin=xClickPos;
        params.topMargin=yClickPos;
```

Answer (score 0):

On my device Galaxy Nexus it is showing animation fine on first time also. May be your device takes time here "mRelativeLayout.addView(scorePop);" Add a little delay after that and then start animation It should run fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am trying to animate the scorePop textView. mScoreText is just another textView, perhaps I should edit it out of my code since it is not relevant to my question.

Comment: This didn't solve it. The text still shows, and disappears after a few seconds, just as before :( Thanks.

Comment: So that's not what you want? Okay you want it to disappear with fade out right?

Comment: Alright.. I have tested on a test project and updated my answer. See and accept if it solves your issue. Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry, the issues is still the same. Did the code work for you without problem? Did the appearing scorePop text fade correctly?

Comment: I have also added an "EDIT" to my OP with something odd I noticed.

Comment: Okay I have tested your code now. Not mine. On my device Galaxy Nexus it is showing animation fine on first time also. May be your device takes time here "mRelativeLayout.addView(scorePop);" Add a little delay after that and then start animation It should run fine.

Comment: Oddly enough, I have created an emulator with Galaxy Nexus and it worked. I am using Nexus 4 and it doesnt work on the device or emulator. Could we possibly try to pinpoint the problem from here?

Comment: Did you check after putting a delay between "mRelativeLayout.addView(scorePop);" and run Animation call?

Comment: I have tried        scoreAnimation.setStartOffset(1000); And this didnt do the trick. Any other way you could suggest for such a delay?

Comment: Try using some other class for animation. Check this 
http://nineoldandroids.com/ or if you can find any other API from Google try that. And a vote up to answer will be much appreciated :) thanks.

Comment: user3249477 had the answer that worked for me. I cannot vote you up because of my reputation, but your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try it...

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fadein);

    txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

    // load the animation
    animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fade_in);

    // set animation listener
    animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);

    // button click event
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // start the animation
            txtMessage.startAnimation(animFadein);
        }
    });
```